# Mysql тип time select остаток времени

Tags: mysql, select, datetime

Есть таблица 'date' в нем столбец 'TimeEnd' тип данных (Time) как мне селектом отобразить остаток времени от столбца 'TimeEnd'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сделал так SELECT '23:59:59'-'13:56:36' но этим показывает только остаток часа и не знаю правильно ли это?

Comment: *не знаю правильно ли это?* Нет, неправильно. Используй [TIMEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00','13:56:36');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]